# I have around 1200 csv files without field headers. Opening each csv file takes huge amount of time as the file size is aroung 30 mb. I

Tags: excel, vba

I have around 1200 csv files without field headers. Opening each csv file takes huge amount of time as the file size is aroung 30 mb. I need to get unique of three columns and than sum based on these unique from a different field.

Not sure if this is doable. Also i am new to vba code.

Please let me know if you can help in this

Pravin

Comment: First of all - have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Second - Don't use VBA for that. Use Get & Transform

Comment: Can you add a link to get & transorm help page? Or example code?

Answer (score 0):

That's too big a job for Excel.  Access isn't going to do it for you either.  Consider using SQL Server or R for this kind of thing.

SQL Script:

```
--BULK INSERT MULTIPLE FILES From a Folder 

    --a table to loop thru filenames drop table ALLFILENAMES
    CREATE TABLE ALLFILENAMES(WHICHPATH VARCHAR(255),WHICHFILE varchar(255))

    --some variables
    declare @filename varchar(255),
            @path     varchar(255),
            @sql      varchar(8000),
            @cmd      varchar(1000)


    --get the list of files to process:
    SET @path = 'C:\Dump\'
    SET @cmd = 'dir ' + @path + '*.csv /b'
    INSERT INTO  ALLFILENAMES(WHICHFILE)
    EXEC Master..xp_cmdShell @cmd
    UPDATE ALLFILENAMES SET WHICHPATH = @path where WHICHPATH is null


    --cursor loop
    declare c1 cursor for SELECT WHICHPATH,WHICHFILE FROM ALLFILENAMES where WHICHFILE like '%.csv%'
    open c1
    fetch next from c1 into @path,@filename
    While @@fetch_status <> -1
      begin
      --bulk insert won't take a variable name, so make a sql and execute it instead:
       set @sql = 'BULK INSERT Temp FROM ''' + @path + @filename + ''' '
           + '     WITH ( 
                   FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', 
                   ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'', 
                   FIRSTROW = 2 
                ) '
    print @sql
    exec (@sql)

      fetch next from c1 into @path,@filename
      end
    close c1
    deallocate c1


    --Extras

    --delete from ALLFILENAMES where WHICHFILE is NULL
    --select * from ALLFILENAMES
    --drop table ALLFILENAMES
```

R Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
df <- list.files(full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  lapply(read_csv) %>% 
  bind_rows
```